# CSS: how to make children fit parent's width

Tags: css

I create parent element with a number of `div` children elements that I then calculate width for in JavaScript, depending on `data-value` attribute.

If I sum up the calculated width for all children I will end up with 100%. But for some reason children would not really occupy 100% of parent's width: a portion of white pixels appears right after the last child.

This is a Fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVUy/42/

Chrome and Firefox render it fine, I face this problem in Safari and Opera (please see the image below).

[image: Rendered component across different browsers]

Besides that, `overflow` property does not work as expected, as children elements overlap the parent `div` (again, relevant only in Safari and Opera).

Questions:

1. Is there other (right) way to make children fit parent?
2. Rounded corners and `overflow: hidden` for the parent, can I make it look the same across all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added css:

```
#component>div{height:100%;}
#component>div:first-of-type{border-radius:30px 0 0 30px;}
#component>div:last-of-type{border-radius: 30px;}
```

Edit in js:

```
$('#component').children().not(':last').each(function () {
```

What happens:
The last div will not float left, and will just fill the space that is left. 
I added rounded corners to the first and last div to fix the corner issue. the last div has a 30px radius in every corner, because the div is actualy behind the other divs (you can see this with inspect element)

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/tqVUy/48/

Comment: Works great and occupies the parent. I knew I miss something.

Comment: The problem with rounded corners though: if we have first or last child too narrow, then `border-radius` is calculated wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVUy/52/

Answer (score 2):

I also face that type of problem. That's why define **border-radius** to the child also. Write like this:

```
#component > div:first-child{
    border-radius:30px 0 0 30px;
}
#component > div:last-child{
    border-radius:0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tqVUy/49/

Comment: Almost solves my second question. But still there is a problem: if we have first or last child too narrow, then `border-radius` is acting wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVUy/52/